# compilation error in killable thread class

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to design a killable_thread class which derives from std::thread.

The class should have a member named die(), which can be invoked to kill the thread.

My [first attempt](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f03b069189bda2ae) ignores the problem of leaking resources. It simply tries to invoke the destructor, but it doesn't compile:

```
/** killable_thread

    A class that inherits the thread class to provide a kill() operation.
    version 1.0 : only kills the thread. Ignores resources.

**/

#ifndef KILLABLE_THREAD
#define KILLABLE_THREAD

#include <thread>       /// thread
#include <iostream>     /// cout, endl


struct killable_thread : std::thread
{
   /// inherit the thread class' constructor
   /// [CPL], $20.3.5.1
   using std::thread::thread;
   using std::thread::operator=;

   ~killable_thread()
   {
   }

   void die()
   {
      ~killable_thread();
   }
};


void f();


int main()
{
   killable_thread kt {f};

   kt.die();

   std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
}


void f()
{
}

#endif  ///  KILLABLE_THREAD
```

The compilation error is:

```
main.cpp: In member function 'void killable_thread::die()':
main.cpp:28:7: error: no match for 'operator~' (operand type is 'killable_thread')

       ~killable_thread();
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How should I go about it?

Comment: Calling an object's destructor from within its member function is risky - why do you need to do this?

Comment: Well, how else can I terminate the thread?

Comment: You can't. The only type-safe to kill a thread in C++ is by the thread throwing an exception that unwinds all of its scope, and returning from the original thread function. Furthermore, this has absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with calling some object's destructor. `std::thread` is just an object. No different from `std::cout`, in that respect. The only thing that's materially different about it is that there's an execution thread linked to it. And it's specified that if it's destroyed while the thread is still running, the whole program will abort. Threads don't work this way.

Comment: OK. Thanks for that explanation. But what explains the compilation error? The compiler doesn't recognize that `~killable_thread()` refers to the destructor; it interprets `~` as the negation operator.

Comment: I also quote Stroustrup ["C++ Programming Language", 4th Ed, pg 1218], `Many tasks involve a request loop. ... A "kindly commit suicide" message would allow the receiving thread to release all resources and then terminate.`

Comment: `this->~killable_thread();` or `(*this).~killable_thread();` would help the compiler.

Comment: @Sam, did you read my quotation from Stroustrup (above)?

Comment: Yes. But "terminate" does not mean "invoking your own destructor". It means return from the original thread function. As I wrote, the execution thread, and a `std::thread` object, are not the same. In fact, a thread cannot possibly invoke its own destructor. If a joinable thread is still running at the time its `std::thread` destructor gets invoked, the whole program terminates; and the thread still has to be running in order to have it invoke its destructor. And invoking the destructor of a `std::thread` after its execution thread has been detached accomplishing absolutely nothing whatsoever.

Comment: @Sam, OK. I'll try throwing an exception in the `die()` member and catching it in the client code.

Comment: Still won't work. An exception can only be caught by the same execution thread. Your exception will throw, and the thread will terminate. That's it.

Comment: @Sam, got it. An exception can't be conveyed across threads. But, an exception_ptr can. I'll try that.

Answer (score 2):

```
~killable_thread();
```

Compiler interprets it like *apply the unary `operator~` to a temporary object created with the default constructor `killable_thread()`*. To call the destructor like a method you should invoke it like bellow:

```
this->~killable_thread();
```

or

```
(*this).~killable_thread();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the “this” keyword:

```
this->~killable_thread();
```

Another way is to write:

```
delete this;
```

However, as mentioned above, calling the destructor in a method is not recommended

Comment: `delete this` also has undefined behaviour unless the current object (`*this`) was created using operator `new`