# killable_thread class terminating

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to design a killable_thread class which derives from **std::thread**. This is subsequent to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49831152/compilation-error-in-killable-thread-class) on this subject and is [version 2](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6cdc5c6dc6767d2).

Here's the source code for the killable_thread class (v2):

```
#include <thread>       /// thread
#include <exception>        /// exception_ptr
#include <iostream>     /// cout, endl


template<typename Tsk,
         typename... Args>
class killable_thread : public std::thread
{
private:
   std::exception_ptr& pex;

public:
   /// inherit the thread class' constructor
   /// [CPL], $20.3.5.1
   using std::thread::thread;
   using std::thread::operator=;

   killable_thread(std::exception_ptr& pe, 
                   Tsk tsk, 
                   Args... args) :
      thread {tsk, args...},
      pex {pe}
   {
   }

   void die()
   {
      try
      {
         std::cout << "diag: dying..." << std::endl;

         throw std::runtime_error 
                    {"thread instructed to die."};
      }
      catch (std::exception& e)
      {
         /** Set the exception_ptr to point to
             this exception, so that it may be 
             propagated out of this thread. **/
         pex = std::current_exception();
      }
   }
};
```

The **tester** is at the same link as above:

```
/// Tester ...

/// declarations ...
void test1();
void f();

std::exception_ptr pex {};


int main()
{
   test1();
}


void test1()
{
   try
   {
      killable_thread<decltype(f)> kt {pex, f};

      kt.die();

      if (pex)
         std::rethrow_exception(pex);

      std::cout << "thread didn't die."
                << std::endl;
   }
   catch (std::exception& e)
   {
      std::cout << "exception: " << e.what()
                << std::endl;
   }
}


void f()
{
}
```

I get the following runtime error:

```
diag: dying...
terminate called without an active exception
bash: line 7: 22929 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./a.out
```

That is, though I handle the exception and set the exception_ptr within the **die**() member, the tester aborts because I don't join() with the thread.

When I do join() with the thread however in [this version of the tester](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1653bc805a78224e), the runtime error disappears (naturally):

```
void test1()
{
   try
   {
      killable_thread<decltype(f)> kt {pex, f};

      kt.die();

      kt.join();

      if (pex)
         std::rethrow_exception(pex);

      std::cout << "thread didn't die."
                << std::endl;
   }
   catch (std::exception& e)
   {
      std::cout << "exception: " << e.what()
                << std::endl;
   }
}
```

The message in this case is:

```
diag: dying...
exception: thread instructed to die.
```

In fact, this is what I want **killable_thread** to do, *without* join()ing in the tester.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: You realize that `die()` is throwing the exception in your main thread and does nothing with the thread running `f()`, right? I think you're going about this the wrong way. What problem are you actually trying to solve with `killable_thread`?

Comment: As @DarkFalcon says plus:   _"How can I get this to work?"_:  You can't.  The only way to kill a thread without undefined behaviour from the Operating System is to: in the thread (repeatedly) test an atomic `please_exit` variable and then cleanly exit by throwing an exception or gracefully exiting back to the top level.

Comment: This is the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) you need to get out of your solution space and think more about the original problem you are trying to solve.  There is a better way.

Comment: @DarkFalcon, I am trying to design a method to tell a running thread to stop running and release its resources.

Comment: "I am trying to design a method to tell a running thread to stop running and release its resources." Why? What problem are you trying to solve by doing that?

Comment: @Jive, This is wrt Stroustrup's comment [CPL, 4th Ed, pg 1217] `I would like to ask remaining tasks to stop once I have an answer.` Actually, I now see that what I have is in fact a solution, because it allows me to stop a running thread, which is exactly what I want.